# Tracking outgoing twilio sms messages for identify when replying

Tags: node.js, sms, twilio

I'm using twilio service with nodejs server for my chat app, and i'd like to create a connection between my app and end users using sms messages.
I'm using this code in node.js to send an sms message:

```
    client.messages.create({
    to: to,
    from: "+MY_TWILIO_PONE",
    body: body
}, function (err, message) { ... }
```

and it's working fine.  My problem is that when a user reply this message, i can't find a single id that connects his incoming sms to the outgoing message.
I must mention that i'm using a single twilio phone number for sending all outgoing SMS messages.

Searching on Twilio docs and over the web offers to use cookies in order to store the conversation, but this is a solution that works only if the first message was sent from outside the app, and not vice versa.

Can you suggest me how can i solve this issue?

Comment: What about MessageSid ?https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters

Comment: Ita doesnt help me because when user replies he gets a new messageSid, regardless the original one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there's no way to track a direct response to an outgoing SMS message from the Twilio API.

Have you considered just associating the SMS responses based on the number you sent them to? If you store the details of the sent message and the number you sent it to, then you can check the from number of an [incoming message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) and associate it that way.

Does that help at all?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately your solution won't help, because i am trying to create a many - to one - to many relation:  i have list of users in my app, and im using a single twilio number to send sms messages to many clients.  So the moment two app-users will send a message to the same sms-client, i will have a problem to determinate which app-user to send the incoming reply message from the sms-client.

Comment: Are there any other SMS service companies out there that can provide me such solution?  Does anyone knows?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible, the SMS standard doesn't account for reply to IDs. You might want to check out this tutorial on masking numbers over SMS that shows how you'd accomplish this with a pool of numbers: https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/node/express

Comment: thanks, i'll dive into this solutions, looks promising

Comment: Now nearly 3 years later is this still true @philnash? When I was looking into the cookie features I expected I could set a cookie on the status callback from my outgoing text and then have it returned on the incoming text response but the cookie isn't there. Seems like that would be a pretty straight forward way to let users connect the conversation.

Comment: @SteveHiner Thing is, there's no way in SMS messaging applications to reply to a particular message (open your SMS app and try to respond to the second to last message someone sent you). Any SMS conversation is chronological scoped by the to and from number. So if you have sent the user a message and they have replied, the best you can do is guess they replied to the last message. Does that help at all?

Comment: @philnash I realize that and I know I can work around it. It's not really a big deal to work around it even. It wasn't that I wanted to know they replied to THAT particular message, it just would have been a little more convenient if the cookie could be set before they respond. I'll probably still use them to make it easier to tie the conversation together once they do respond. "Reality - Expectations = Happiness" and reading that Twilio has cookie support set my expectations a little higher than the reality. I'm a big boy though so I'll be ok. ;-) I am finding Twilio to be very cool.

Comment: Ah, sorry Steve. I think the cookies work based on the idea that Twilio is the server and an incoming text is a client request and that doesn't work the other way around when Twilio is making the request. I'm glad you can work around it though and sorry to disappoint your expectations.